# Where can i find good resources for building custom ui for titanium apps

Tags: titanium

Where can i find good resources for building custom ui for titanium apps like triplingo app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for custom UI, you obviously, need to hire a designer fluent in Photoshop, Illustrator or whatever graphics program.

If your looking for code to style said apps, then look no further than the docs, specifically the `backgroundImage` attribute of every view in titanium.

For example to style a custom button, do this:

```
var more_btn = Ti.UI.createButton({
    backgroundImage : 'More-1.png', // Custom UI
    backgroundFocusedImage : 'More-2.png', // Custom UI when clicked
    top : 271,
    left : 173,
    width : 135,
    height : 40
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of tutorials Appcelerator provided for custom UI development:

1. [Custom UI Components](http://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2011/08/forging-titanium-episode-3-custom-ui-components.html&ei=aQcvUJmsLsj2sgaczYHQCA&usg=AFQjCNEEcWU_i5BgnyaW_ngzC-f9U6vMoA&sig2=yQtxxT2zkIR4gf-kMiu9TQ&cad=rja)
2. [Building an Advanced Transaction UI with Titanium](http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/building-an-advanced-transaction-ui-with-titanium.html)

I recommend you watch the forging titanium video series for more advanced techniques [HERE](http://vimeopro.com/appcelerator/forging-titanium)